# How to locally test interaction with external contracts (chainlink and pyth oracles )?

Tags: testing, anchor-test, fork

I have a Solana smart contract (written with Anchor) that interacts with Pyth and Chainlink Solana oracles. In EVM world, we would either redeploy the necessary contracts locally in the test start-up and configure them ourselves or perform fork-testing (forking the state of the mainnet and running tests independently locally).

Problems with forking:

- I've found [this answer](https://solana.stackexchange.com/a/2076/1810) on how to "fork" Solana programs and accounts, but I am not sure if I can configure it so the anchor test runner starts up and loads the accounts for me.
- I am not sure how to interact with the program from JS after it's in my local network. I don't have the IDL available.

Problems with setting things up manually:

- I've found [this answer](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/623/how-to-include-other-programs-and-test-cpis-on-localnet-using-anchor) on how to retrieve the on-chain programs and *insert* them inside the anchor test runner, but I am not sure how to interact with the program from JS after it's in my local network. I don't have the IDL available.

If anyone has had the experience of writing localnet tests for either of these oracles or any other external program, please share your experience.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the issue by making use of `Anchor.toml` `[test.validator.clone]` attribute ([docs](https://www.anchor-lang.com/docs/manifest))

1. First I clone the necessary program `solana program dump --url devnet HEvSKofvBgfaexv23kMabbYqxasxU3mQ4ibBMEmJWHny chainlink.so`
2. Update the `Anchor.toml` file:

```
# Because I am copying many accounts in my tests, I need to wait quite a long time
[test]
startup_wait = 100000

# The cluster from which I am cloning the accounts
[test.validator]
url = "https://api.devnet.solana.com"

# The external programs I want to deploy
[[test.genesis]]
address = "<chainlink validator address>"
program = "chainlink.so"

# Addresses that I want to clone (e.g. price feed account from chainlink or pyth)
[[test.validator.clone]]
address = "<address of account I'm using in my tests>"

[[test.validator.clone]]
address = "<address of account I'm using in my tests>"
```